# VS2013 LightSwitch Project was OK now won't build. (Machine has been moved onto domain)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-lightswitch, localdb, lightswitch-2013

Lightswitch solution with an external database was able to be built and debugged.
It has lain dormant and in the meantime the development machine and myself have moved onto a domain.
Now an attempt to build the solution gives:
Error   15  An error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server instance '(LocalDB)\v11.0'.
Login failed for user 'MyNewDomain\MyNewUserName'.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v4.0\Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets    160 10  TrueTrackLightSwitch2013

It seems I need to tell (LocalDB)\V11 about a new user (MyNewUserName) but I don't know how to do this.

It also raises concerns in that I want to pass the maintenance of this project to another developer  once I get it going again.

The project is accessing data from an external SqlServer 2008 database. This external database holds the Aspnet tables for form based security.

I don't understand where '(LocalDB)\v11.0' comes into the picture

thanks

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to delete folder as per the steps in the following link.
The delete database step failed for me saying database did not exist.
But I was able to open my project and rebuild it.
[MSDN LightSwitchForm Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/LightSwitchDev11Beta/thread/484fb538-81eb-4eb6-b0bd-980dc85c5f7e)

The Answer that worked was:

*Matt on the LightSwitch team got me running again:*

*1) Delete the directory at:
C:\Users{your user name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0
Note: replace "{your user name}" with the name you logged in with.
2) On your Windows start Menu type in CMD and press enter. When the Command Window comes up type:
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"
then:
sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
It will say:
LocalDB instance "v11.0" deleted.
Then open a LightSwitch project and run it and it should then work*